# Strong bias from Linear SVR meta model

Tags: forecasting, svm, bias, meta-learning

I have built nine meta models based on the model stacking principle, which I compare to a reference model for a number of time series. See the results below. The 22 base models that are trained on 70% of the training data produce forecasts on the last 30% of the training data on which the meta models are trained. These are then validated on the test set (last 20% of all data).

The Lin. SVR model's hyperparameters are set as follows, with other hyperparams. set to their default values:
`C=0.1, fit_intercept=False, loss='squared_epsilon_insensitive', dual=False`

Interestingly, the Lin. SVR models perform very poorly, which is an exception to the other models. Looking at their forecasts, we see a strong, consistent negative bias. What would explain this behaviour, and how could it be remedied?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the issue I discovered I was able to correct the bias by setting `fit_intercept` to `True`. The `scikit-learn` docs for `LinearSVR` say the following for this argument:

> Whether to calculate the intercept for this model. If set to false, no intercept will be used in calculations (i.e. data is expected to be already centered).

While the data is centred (using `sklearn.preprocessing.scale()`), setting `fit_intercept` to `False` generated the results in the question above.